# How to bind user control width same as the templated GridViewColumn?

Tags: wpf, binding, user-controls, datatemplate

I have a user control named `SegmentedProgressBar` and it has `StackPanel` as a child. I want to use my user control in a ListView Column and when column resized, I want the StackPanel to resize too. I tried below code but it doesnt resize when the column resized. How can I fix this problem?

**SegmentedProgressBar**

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.SegmentedProgressBar"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="20" d:DesignWidth="300" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="ucsg">
<StackPanel x:Name="spanel" Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Blue" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    
</StackPanel>
```

**MainWindow**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <ListView Name="listview1">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                     <GridViewColumn x:Name="SPBarCell"  Width="100" Header="Segmented" >
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <local:SegmentedProgressBar x:Name="test" Width="{Binding Path=Width, ElementName=SPBarCell}" Height="20" Margin="0"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>

                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

[image]

Comment: Can't reproduce the issue? What's the purpose of ContentLength dependency property in SegmentedProgressBar?

Comment: I have updated my question minimizing  to reproduce issue.

Comment: Still the same behavior. Can be the issue related to logic in code behind of SegmentedProgressBar?

Comment: I have checked my codebehind and solved the issue after your comment. There was code setting `Width` and `Height` to `100` in constructor. I didn't know it effects resizing. Removing that code the problem has gone. Thanks so much.